# How to get window background and text color for theme in java code in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-theme

I have created multiple themes for my app in styles.xml. All themes use different window background, text color and other attributes. i want to create some buttons and preview for themes in preferences. How do I get the text color for all the themes?

I want to get text color for R.style.AppTheme, R.style.myTheme1, R.style.myTheme2, ...

How to get this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a static variable (Hashmap) and initialize like so

```
colors.put("Name of activity class","Color name");
```

and every time you open an activity pass its name to the map and get the color name

Comment: Probably you just didn't understand the question. There is only one activity in my app